# Elevate points from imported DXF file to heights in LAS databse

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, dxf, las, z-value

Is it possible to elevate points that are on the same plane in dxf to heights that are in LAS? I have imported dxf and las file in Arcmap but I need guidance or at least direction where to start looking for solution.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify a DXF with ArcGIS. If you import it to a GDB, you can then use [Add Surface Information](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-surface-information.htm) to assign the LAS dataset's elevation to your features.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The whole idea behind this is that I have a point cloud the we made with quadcopter and a map of points that were messured on the site. Now I would like to elevate the points from the site to the height of the nearest point in the point cloud.

Comment: Ok I have solved the problem with importing DXF, creating a raster from las dataset and geting proper height atributes for my points (rastervalu). Now I cannot figure it out how to export this data to AutoCAD. If I export it as dwg or dxf points do not have Z POSITION. Only X and Y. Anybody have any solution for this problem. My exctracted points have attribute table POSITION_X , POSITION_Y and RASTERVALU. I even tried to rename RASTERVALU to POSITION_Z but sadly with no results.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with importing DXF, creating a raster from LAS dataset and getting the proper height attributes for my points (RASTERVALU).

A caveat was that AutoCAD did not recognize RASTERVALU attribute in shapefile as elevation. To bypass this and import shapefile from ArcGIS, one can use the steps described in "Importing ESRI shape file into Civil 3D shows zero elevations" in Autodesk knowledge base.